# Scala for loop with enum yield issue

Tags: scala

I'm trying the funky for loops in Scala to loop over a List of Case Class objects:

```
case class SimpleCredits(credits: CreditType, quantity: Int)

val s = for{
   i <- Users.findCreditsByUser(u)
   t <- i.credits
   if(i.quantity > 0)
} yield t
```

Intellij doesn't like the resultant s and I can't figure out why.

When I try and compile it I get:

```
value filter is not a member of enums.CreditType.CreditType
```

I've googled this and saw posts of a few people with similar issues and possible baggage but can't find anything concrete.

So, should it work or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achive is this:

```
val s = for{
   i <- Users.findCreditsByUser(u)
   if (i.quantity > 0)
   t = i.credits
} yield t
```

Or equivalently:

```
val s = for{
   i <- Users.findCreditsByUser(u)
   if(i.quantity > 0)
} yield i.credits
```